# Xamarin.Forms Routing.RegisterRoute() Doesn't registering any changes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I have routing registry in AppShell.xaml.cs

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        BindingContext = App.Container.Resolve<AppShellViewModel>();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(AdvertismentDetailViewModel), typeof(AdvertisementDetailPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LoginViewModel), typeof(LoginPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(UserDetailViewModel), typeof(UserDetailPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(AdvertismentListViewModel), typeof(AdvertisementDetailPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(RegisterViewModel), typeof(RegisterPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(UserProfileViewModel), typeof(UserProfilePage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MyAdvertisementsListViewModel), typeof(MyAdvertisementsListPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MyAdvertisementDetailViewModel), typeof(MyAdvertisementDetailPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(PublisherChatViewModel), typeof(PublisherChatView));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(YekkaDetailViewModel), typeof(YekkaDetailPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ForgotPasswordViewModel), typeof(ForgotPasswordPage));
    }
}
```

Now, if I **add new route** or if I **delete them all** it **will not take any effect.**
I noticed this when I added this last route. I have rebuilded, deleted bin,obj folders. Thanks :)

Comment: are you saying that even if you delete all the routes they are still working?  I would try deleting the app from the device/emulator before redeploying it

Comment: 1) In the Shell navigation doc, see this important note: **All items in the Shell hierarchy have a route associated with them. If you don't set a route, one is generated at runtime.**  That means there are some **implicit** routes, based on the XAML inside `<Shell> ... </Shell>`. 2) **It will not take any effect** is vague. Please give an **exact example** of a) What you tried to do (code and/or user action), b) What you expected to happen, c) What actually happened. d) **I've never seen** route declarations like those. Why is the name based on the viewmodel? Show code that uses one of those.

Comment: OK, after a whole day of debigging I realized that my app have two AppShell classes, each for different purpose and I had to add my newly created route in the LoginShell instead of default AppShel. Shame on me :) But that still does't explain how app worked after I deleted all the routes, it was solved after I redeployed the app to testing device and restarted my computer. Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to reinstall the app on a testing device.